# How to change a value form ObservableCollection<AnyClass> with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, observablecollection

I have a `ObservableCollection<AnyClass>` collection. This collection has data like ID, first name, second name, address, pin, city, Salary and Description.

I want to change the description of this collection whose id is 10 or 12 or any ID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to make sure: You are not doing anything with collection itself. You are modifying objects, that are only storred in this collection.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
foreach(var item in collection.Where(x => x.ID == 10))
{
    item.Description = newDescription;
}
```

Comment: Daniel, I want to update the exisiting collection. The demo you have given needs to add object in another collection.

Comment: `item` is the item inside your original collection. `item.Description = newDescription;` changes the description of the item in your original collection. It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is old question, someone may find my answer useful.

You can do this by using LINQ to find necessary item using appropriate predicate and then modify.

```
var selectedItem = myCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 10);

if (selectedItem != null)
{
   selectedItem.Description = "Do something";
}
```

Hope it helped to someone.